# Script LEMP para Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: php, linux, nginx, mariadb

Hay algún script para instalar el stack LEMP entero en Ubuntu/Debian por el estilo del que hay para CentOS (Centmin Mod) ?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; using http://easyengine.io/  `ee stack install --all`

Instalar un Stack LAMP básico en Ubuntu/Debian siempre ha sido muy fácil usando Tasksel:

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

Sin embargo instalar un Stack LEMP en Debian/Ubuntu no era tan sencillo hasta que apareció EasyEngine. Aunque pueda parecer por su web que solo monta WordPress, es mucho más que eso.

Échale un ojo a los tutoriales que tienen para montar prácticamente de todo:

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/

Por ejemplo:

```
ee stack install --all
```

Instalará LEMP completo + PostFix ( Postfix es el precio que hay que pagar a cambio de instalar un LEMP en una sola linea de código :)